# The transaction has been reverted to the initial state. The called function should be payable if you send value

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, remix

the Error being specified is

```
revert
    The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.
Debug the transaction to get more information.
```

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier:MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.8;
contract Giftcard{
    event UniqueCardId(uint indexed Id,address indexed owner);
    //Enter The Giftcard amount
    //Pay the gift card by making multiple transations
    //require(giftcard owner should approve the withdrawl )
    address[]  Giftcardowners;
    mapping(address => uint) amountUploaded;
    function Addamount() external payable{
        require(msg.value >= 1 ether,"Gift card amount to small");
        amountUploaded[msg.sender] = msg.value;
        Giftcardowners.push(msg.sender);
        emit UniqueCardId(Giftcardowners.length-1,msg.sender);
    }
    function GetGiftcard(uint _cardId) payable external {
        require(Giftcardowners.length > _cardId,"Id doesnot exits");
        address owner = Giftcardowners[_cardId-1];
        uint amount = amountUploaded[owner];
        require(amount >= 1 ether,"transfered is less than 1 ether");
       // (bool successs,)  = payable(msg.sender).call{value:amount}("");
        //require(successs,"transaction reverted");
        payable(msg.sender).transfer(1 ether);
    }
    function getBalance() external view  returns(uint balance){
        return address(this).balance;
    }
}
```

Firstly I called the `Addamount` function by paying more than 1 ether to the smart contract
now after that when the `GetGiftcard` function is called the transaction is reverted. I am unable to find a solution

unable to understand the concept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is here

```
address owner = Giftcardowners[_cardId-1];
```

should be

```
address owner = Giftcardowners[_cardId];
```

When you call `addAmount`, this line executes

```
  Giftcardowners.push(msg.sender);
```

in the `Giftcardowners` array you have only 1 item

```
Giftcardowners=[0x7EF2e0048f5bAeDe046f6BF797943daF4ED8CB47]
```

when you call the `GetGiftcard`, you need to pass `_cardId=0`, you are actually assigning the index of the array as the id. when you pass 0, index will be -1 here

```
address owner = Giftcardowners[_cardId-1];
```

You cannot pass 1 to get 1-1=0, because you have this condition

```
require(Giftcardowners.length > _cardId,"Id doesnot exits");
```